# Como usar atributos HTML5 data- com Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como usar atributos com " - " do html5 e outros plugins com os Html helper do asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

Tem um parâmetro chamado `htmlAttributte` do tipo `object`, praticamente todos os componentes que eu conheço tem esse parâmetro disponível em seu construtor, com ele você pode setar os atributos `html` do componente, como por exemplo um `label`:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "control-label", @data_time = "teste" })
```

**A unica restrição de seu uso é que você não deve usar o "-" e sim o "_", como separação. Como citado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917596/html-helper-with-special-htmlattributes).**

O exemplo acima será renderizado no browser assim:

```html
<label class="control-label" data-time="teste" for="Nome">Nome</label>
```

Acredito que isso ajude a resolver seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Crie um [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), que representa uma estrutura de par valor aonde os elementos poderam ser as opções dos `helpers` do MVC ASP.NET

```
@{ 
    IDictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    options.Add("data-val", "true");
    options.Add("data-val-required", "O campo Dias é obrigatório.");
}
```

Chame-o assim:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Dias, options)
```

Ou Pode chamar direto assim também:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Dias, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", "true" }, { "data-val-required", "O campo Dias é obrigatório." } })
```